# How to Make a particular Cell Required in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all i will give an `Excel Document` for the user with some basic information as follows

[image]

Now if the user leaves a cell which is required i would like to prompt him a message saying that it is a required value with in the excel.

I have referred to [some articles](http://www.ehow.com/how_7497735_make-cell-required-excel-2007.html)

But i am unable to achieve what I required so can any one help. Also I would like to know is it possible to apply `Regular expression validators` with in the `Excel`. Something like `Date format` should be `mm/dd/yyyy` and `SSN` should be `9 digited` like that..

I tried some thing like but this didn't prompt me any `error or Dialog`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeSave(Cancel As Boolean)
If Sheet1.Range("A3:B3").Value = "" Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "Cannot print until required cells have been completed!"
Cancel = True      
End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: For your first question, you should probably use event procedure. For your second question, did you try to tweak [Data Validation](http://www.contextures.com/xldataval01.html)?

Comment: These are two separate, unrelated questions, and therefore you should post them in two separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

Part 1

That code has a few issues

1. You need a `Workbook` event - there is no WorkSheet_BeforeSave event
2. You cant test for two blank cells with `Sheet1.Range("A3:B3").Value = ""`
3. If the code is running then events are already enabled, so this line `Application.EnableEvents = True` is redundant

Something like this test for both A3 and B3 being non blank on the leftmost sheet

{code goes in the `ThisWorkbook` module}

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("a3:b3")) <> 2 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot print until required cells have been completed!"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

While you can use a Regex for part 2, plain data validation should work fine,ie

a) You can use an "allow" Date in Data Validation

b) You could use a Whole Number between 100,000,000 and 999,999,999 for a 9 digit number

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Part 2 (Regular Expression thing)

You can write a user-defined function in VBA and use it in Excel. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086270/how-to-extract-text-within-a-string-of-text/7087145#7087145) that extracts parts of a string using RegEx, but with a bit of tweaking you can use it to do validation.