# Google Sheets Trim after either of characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a column of cells in Google Sheets with text in the following formats:

```
PLAYBILL59; Code Description Here
BROADWAYBOX59: Code Description Here
TICKETCODE: Code Description Here
```

I want to create a formula that deletes everything after and including either a colon or semi-colon, that would leave:

```
PLAYBILL59
BROADWAYBOX59
TICKETCODE
```

I've been trying for hours with no luck.

Any suggestions very appreciated.

Comment: Probably a hefty LEFT FIND LEN assembly, greatly simplified by using a few columns, unless you wish to use a macro.

Comment: I tried using =IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(V180,FIND(";",V180))),V180), but that leaves the semi-colon, and i can't work out to find **either** a colon or a semi-colon.

Comment: So i came up with this, but can't work out how to remove the colons and semi-colons    =IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(V180,FIND("; ",V180))),IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(V180,FIND(": ",V180)))))

Comment: That edit makes a huge difference in the complexity, good stuff @D.Dimitrioglo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that your colum is A, then you can use `REGEXEXTRACT` in your formula like

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "[A-Z0-9-a-z]+")
```

[image]

Comment: This work perfectly for the example I gave, but I didn't give you the full picture. Some cells have information in the format 59E59-reg or 59E59-ABC, and I need those to stay the same if there are no colons or semi-colons. Thanks so much for alerting me to this method.

Comment: Is there a similar function to `RegexExtract` in Excel? That looks like a handy function.

Comment: @BruceWayne I do not know about Excel, I'm using only google spreadsheets

Comment: THIS IS IT! Thank you! Genius

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo - Ah, okay.  FYI for anyone in the future, I found [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7087145/4650297) which includes a VBA macro for extracting regex in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text string is in A1, try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "; Code Description Here",""), ": Code Description Here", "")
```

Comment: This is a very good/simple/obvious way to do what you want if you know you'll have those strings between.

Comment: "and assuming `; Code Description Here` don't change"