# Excel VBA Split on regexp

Tags: regex, string, vba, excel

I am writing a Excel VBA macro and need to split a string on a number.  What I had hoped would work is this:

```
Split("ABC2_DEF",[0-9]*)(0)
```

Which would give me

```
ABC
```

Every combination I tried either interprets literally or is invalid.  I cannot seem to find how to use a regex in the Split function and perhaps it is not possible.  I was hoping to avoid a brute force method.  Thanks.

EDIT:
I found the function [RegexExtract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086270/how-to-extract-text-within-a-string-of-text) that worked great.  Would still like to know if I can natively Split on regex.

Comment: To be clear, you can use Regex to do what you want with find/replace...but you're looking specifically for using it with `SPLIT()`?

Comment: VBA regex  has no `Split` method. You can only `Execute`, i.e. *match* (or replace with `Substitute`, or check for a match with `Test`).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  The `RegexExtract` function I linked to is working well for me.