# Regex to extract inconsistent postal codes from string

Tags: regex, excel, vba, function, postal-code

Using the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086270/how-to-extract-text-within-a-string-of-text/7087145#7087145), I'm looking to extract postal codes from a list of irregular data in Excel.

Below is a sample of what my data looks like:

> Brampton L6P 2G9 ON Canada
>
> M5B2R3 Toronto ON
>
> Toronto M5J 0A6 ON Canada
>
> M1H1T7 Canada
>
> Toronto M4P1T8 ON Canada
>
> MISSISUAGABRAMPTON L5M6S6 ON Canada
>
> 333 Sea Ray Inisfil l4e2y6 ON Canada

To call the function, I'm using the following formula

```
=RegexExtract(A1,"^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$")
```

However the function is not working for me. I think I need to tweak my regex expression in some way but I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: IIR, VBA's regex flavor doesn't support negative look-ahead assertions, and you would also need to remove the anchors with the linked function.  Are you trying to *validate* the postal codes, or just extract them?

Comment: I’m trying to extract them from wherever they are located in the text

Answer (score 4):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

Try,

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(upper(A2), "[A-X]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d")
'alternate
=left(REGEXEXTRACT(upper(A2), "[A-X]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d"), 3)&" "&right(REGEXEXTRACT(upper(A2), "[A-X]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d"), 3)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution however I don't think it will work in Microsoft Excel

Comment: excel doesn't have a RegexExtract function so I thought I would include a google-spreadsheet tag. The pattern is really what you're looking for.

Comment: Good answer  there.+

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 issues.

---

First, the expression - if you need to extract the postal code, you can't anchor your regex with `^` and `$`. The first means "match must occur at the start of the string" and the second means "match must end at the end of the string".  This is only useful if you are validating a postal code, but it obviously can't be used to extract one from your examples because they all contain things *other than* the postal code.
The other problem with the regex is the negative look-ahead assertion `(?!.*[DFIOQU])`, which means "no match can contain the letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U".  To the best of my recollection, this isn't supported in VBScript regex. If I'm mistaken, please correct me in the comments.

That gives you the slightly more pedantic expression:

`[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVX]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][ -]?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d`

I took the liberty of optionally allowing a `-` between the FSA and LDU because I see that a *lot*, particularly from non-Canadians.

---

Second, the function that you're calling (copied below from the linked answer):

> ```
> Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
>                       ByVal extract_what As String, _
>                       Optional separator As String = ", ") As String
>
> Dim allMatches As Object
> Dim RE As Object
> Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
> Dim i As Long, j As Long
> Dim result As String
>
> RE.pattern = extract_what
> RE.Global = True
> Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
>
> For i = 0 To allMatches.count - 1
>     For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).submatches.count - 1
>         result = result & (separator & allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j))
>     Next
> Next
>
> If Len(result) <> 0 Then
>     result = Right$(result, Len(result) - Len(separator))
> End If
>
> RegexExtract = result
>
> End Function
> ```

The first problem is that it is case sensitive. It is also tailored to extracting submatches, which you don't care about - your examples are looking for a single match.

I'd go with this much simpler option that also correctly formats the output:

```
Public Function ExtractCanadianPostalCode(inputText As String) As String
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVX]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][ -]?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        If .Test(inputText) Then
            Dim matches As Object
            Set matches = .Execute(inputText)
            ExtractCanadianPostalCode = UCase$(Left$(matches(0), 3) & " " & Right$(matches(0), 3))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: `"[A-X]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d"` and while I've never actually seen a hyphen in a Canadian postal code, I suppose there are enough Americans in the world to include the possibility.

Comment: @Jeeped TBH, if they didn't need to be valid codes I'd probably use "[A-Z](\d|O)[A-Z][ -]?(\d|O)[A-Z](\d|O)". Using an 'O' for a zero is another *really* common error.

Comment: Yes, I have seen OCR convert zeroes to oh's. That's a very valid point.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. These solutions worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Also, a great ans. +