# Excel VBA Find & Replace Text In A String With Loop

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to replace all the text in a string between the pattern **"&CC[number]:[number]"** and replace it with a **"=="**.

Here is the string. `"T &CC3:5 Q8 Party/ Self-Identify&CC6:8 Male&CC9:11 Female&CC12:15 Q1 Vote"`

This is what I need it to look like `T &CC3:5==&CC6:8==&CC9:11==&CC12:15==`

I know I need to loop through this string but I'm not sure the best way to set this up.

```
Dim stringOne As String
Dim regexOne As Object
Set regexOne = New RegExp

regexOne.Pattern = "([Q])+[0-9]"
regexOne.Global = False
stringOne = "T &CC3:5 Q8 Party/ Self-Identify&CC6:8 Male&CC9:11 Female&CC12:15 Q1 Vote"

Debug.Print regexOne.Replace(stringOne, "==")
End Sub
```

I have also explored using this regular expression `regexOne.Pattern = "([&])+[C]+[C]+[0-9]+[:]+[0-9]"`

I plan to eventually set the variable stringOne to `Range("A1").Text`

Comment: ([CC]+[0-9]*[:][0-9]*)

Comment: If a positive lookahead is supported you could use `(&CC[0-9]+:[0-9]+).*?(?=&|$)` and replace with the first capturing group and == https://regex101.com/r/5o8QVE/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text within a string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086270/how-to-extract-text-within-a-string-of-text)

Comment: @Thefourthbird that would work for sure. How does the positive lookahead work? I have some questions that have double ampersand that break the regex. See https://regex101.com/r/5o8QVE/2 Would there be a way to account for that?

Comment: You could add matching a C after it https://regex101.com/r/z50WZq/1

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird! You are amazing with regex. I need to learn more.

Comment: @Seth You are welcome, I have updated the answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the pattern a bit and use a capturing group and a positive lookahead

```
(&CC[0-9]+:[0-9]+).*?(?=&C|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `&CC[0-9]+:[0-9]+` Match `&CC` 1+ digits, : and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `.*?` Match 0+ times any char except a newline non greedy
- `(?=&C|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is either `&C` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z50WZq/1)

In the replacement use the first capturing group followed by `==`